# Pandas Date rows with missing dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a pandas series that looks like

```
df
               date
2021-05-18 10:02:04
2021-05-18 10:03:02
2021-05-18 10:04:03
2021-05-18 10:07:04
2021-05-18 10:08:03
2021-05-18 10:09:00
2021-05-18 10:10:03
```

Provide the data as a dictionary:

```
 [{'date': Timestamp('2021-05-18 10:02:04.509293079')}, {'date': Timestamp('2021-05-18 10:03:02.709293127')}, {'date': Timestamp('2021-05-18 10:04:03.109292984')}, {'date': Timestamp('2021-05-18 10:07:04.109292984')}, {'date': Timestamp('2021-05-18 10:08:03.109292984')}, {'date': Timestamp('2021-05-18 10:09:00.309293032')}, {'date': Timestamp('2021-05-18 10:10:03.409293175')}]
```

and I calculate the time between dates (the expected time between two dates is around 60 seconds)

```
df['date'] - df['date'].shift(1)

               date            shift
2021-05-18 10:02:04              NaT
2021-05-18 10:03:02  0 days 00:00:58
2021-05-18 10:04:03  0 days 00:01:00
2021-05-18 10:07:04  0 days 00:03:01 <- 3 minutes apart because 2 rows are missing
2021-05-18 10:08:03  0 days 00:00:59
2021-05-18 10:09:00  0 days 00:00:57
2021-05-18 10:10:03  0 days 00:01:03
```

What is the most efficient way to add the missing rows by auto-incrementing the time between dates?

The expected result:

```
               date            shift
2021-05-18 10:02:04              NaT
2021-05-18 10:03:02  0 days 00:00:58
2021-05-18 10:04:03  0 days 00:01:00
2021-05-18 10:05:04  0 days 00:02:00 <- row missing with calculate shift time (by auto-incrementing +60 seconds)
2021-05-18 10:06:05  0 days 00:03:00 <- row missing with calculate shift time (by auto-incrementing +60 seconds)
2021-05-18 10:07:04  0 days 00:01:01
2021-05-18 10:08:03  0 days 00:00:59
2021-05-18 10:09:00  0 days 00:00:57
2021-05-18 10:10:03  0 days 00:01:03
```